# How to deal with relationships with structs in Swift?

Tags: swift, struct, relationship

I was advised to use structs as much as possible in Swift, because so many things are structs already (Int, String, Array, Dictionary, almost everything is).

But if I have a relationship (with a reverse) to deal with, I couldn't come up with a satisfying solution, **especially in the case of datasource for an `UITableView`**. An example out of many: a `Game` object with multiple `Player`, and each `Player` has multiple `Game`.

## approach one

I store all the instances of the same struct in a list, I give an id to each instance, and I fetch the lists every time I need related objects.

```
var allGames: [Game] = []
struct Game {
    let id: String
    var playerIds: [String]
    var players: [Player] {
        get { return allPlayers.filter({ playerIds.contains($0.id) }) }
    }
}
var allPlayers: [Player] = []
struct Player {
    let id: String
    var gameIds: [String]
    var games: [Game] {
        get { return allGames.filter({ gameIds.contains($0.id) }) }
    }
}
```

## approach two

I move away from struct.

```
class Game {
    var players: [Player] = []
}
class Player {
    var games: [Game] = []
}
```

## question

How to deal with relationships with structs in Swift? Is one of the two approaches above a better way than the other, or is there an even better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were told to use structs instead of classes? You've been had. Or you just didn't understand whatever advice you got properly.

structs are *value types*. Classes are *reference types*. That means you can't have references to structs. Two structs = two different objeccts = twice the memory. You can have references to class instances.

Say you have 1000 players all playing the same game. With structs, you have 1000 copies of the game. Worse, the game would have a copy of each player, which each would have a copy of the game, which would have a copy of each player, which each would have a copy of the game, and so on forever.

That's why you make Player and Game *classes*.

Comment: Well, among other advices, Apple uses the example of a `struct Restaurant`: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: Fortunately we have copy-on-write in Swift